# Android Unit Tests - How can I mock an Event Listener button on Android?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, code-coverage

So I need to write unit tests for this code and I don't know how to do it. In my case i need just to coverage "onCategoryButtonsAfterExpand()" method in my code:

Code:

```
 cropSettingsView.getCropSettingsCategoryButton().setCategoryButtonsEventListener(new CategoryButtons.CategoryButtonsEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCategoryButtonsBeforeExpand(CategoryButtons categoryButtons) {
           
         }

         @Override
         public void onCategoryButtonsAfterExpand(CategoryButtons categoryButtons) {
            Handler h = new Handler();
            if(dataHandler.isCropSettingsFirstAccess()) {
               h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                     cropSettingsView.getCropTypeInfoButton().performClick();
                  }
               }, 100);
               dataHandler.setCropSettingsFirstAccess(false);
            }
```

On before setUp() method i mock using this instruction code:

```
when(mockCropSettingsView.getCropSettingsCategoryButton()).thenReturn(mockCategoryButtons);
```

and the code even covers this instruction:

"cropSettingsView.getCropSettingsCategoryButton().setCategoryButtonsEventListener"
I just don't know how to cover this listener.
If anyone can help, I appreciate it. Thank you all.

I was hoping to try to cover the button listener